# PayPal express checkout integration to website

Tags: paypal

I am creating a site for client where I need to create a cart for buying products. And then connect it to PayPal. I want some simple tutorial to do that. And do I need PayPal account info of my client like email and password, that will disclose his account and he may not want to do that. is their a way I can do this if he cannot trust me with this information.

Answer (score 0):

You should test everything in the PayPal sandbox and provide a simple config file or settings panel where your client can enter their own API credentials for working live.

If you're working with PHP, this [PayPal class library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make it very simple to make the Express Checkout API calls, and this [demo kit](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-express-checkout-php-line-items-demo/) will provide a fully functional demo with a static shopping cart to see how it's all plugged together.